# Difference between java.exe and javaw.exe

Tags: java, swing, javaw

Recently I noted that some applications are running on `javaw` (not in `java`). What is the difference between them and how can I run my Swing application on `javaw`?

Comment: Similar question and good answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194750/99717.  Note that the question there asks also about javaws.exe, so not technically a duplicate...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

java.exe is the command where it waits for application to complete untill it takes the next command.
javaw.exe is the command which will not wait for the application to complete. you can go ahead with another commands.

Comment: doesn't javaw.exe also not show console output https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQUAyJYwJ6Q  0:57  http://i.imgur.com/TGsm45f.png

Comment: This answer is incorrect.    

javaw.exe *does* wait until the program completes. It can be used safely as part of `.bat` script for example, and it will wait.    

However, when you _manually_ start non-console programs from `cmd.exe`, the `cmd.exe` will not wait and return to command prompt immediately. Try it with `notepad.exe` vs `ping 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 121):

`java.exe` is the console app while `javaw.exe` is windows app (console-less). You can't have [`Console`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) with `javaw.exe`.

Comment: I'll add that "the console app" here doesn't necessarily mean that "this was run from a console", only that `java.exe` is allowed to access its console.  Running an applet from within a browser on Windows, for example, always uses `java.exe` even if my Java Control Panel is set to _Hide the console window_ or even _Do not start a console window_.

Comment: Following answer seems better to me and has Java documentation references:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194750/99717

Answer (score 46):

The difference is in the [subsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) that each executable targets.

- `java.exe` targets the `CONSOLE` subsystem.
- `javaw.exe` targets the `WINDOWS` subsystem.

Answer (score 15):

The javaw.exe command is identical to java.exe, except that with javaw.exe there is no associated console window

Comment: Technically more correct: With `javaw` there is no associated *console*. The window isn't necessarily created (for example, when you run from an existing console window or completely in background).