# How should I `java -jar a.jar`, then exit java but keep jar

Tags: java, jar, cmd

I want to run jar runnable file on windows.
In `cmd`, I type `java -jar a.jar`, but it will start a java exe  first for a.jar's parent, but I don't want it.(or start java and start a.jar, then exit java but keep jar)
If I only type `a.jar` in `cmd`, it work well, but for some reason, I must start it from java, How should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can try , `javaw`, that is `java`  in a new thread, you may want to look at [Difference between java.exe and javaw.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997718/difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe)