# I tried to put two jar commands in a batch file, but it just won't work

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, command

I tried to put two jar commands in a batch file, but it just won't work.

At first I tried this:

```
@echo off 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar Soulsplit.jar
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar Soulsplit.jar
```

I've also tried:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar Soulsplit.jar & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar Soulsplit.jar
```

if I run those batch files, they will just do one line, I hope someone could help!
It will only run the first command, I expect it to start up two programs.

Just putting one line of command:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar Soulsplit.jar
```

does work.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: It will only run the first command, I expect it to start up two programs.

Comment: Is your program command-line based (do the read from `System.in` and/or print to `System.out`), or are they GUI based, or Windows services?

Answer (score 2):

If you expect the output from your `Soulsplit.jar` to the command line, run `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe` - see [Difference between java.exe and javaw.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997718/difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe).