# How can I run a new process, and close the current program in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar someOtherProgram.jar");
    }
}
```

This effectively runs my other program. However, this program (App) does not close. It is still running (I can tell because it won't let me kill it in Eclipse). The only way to close this program is by killing the process that corresponds to `someOtherProgram.jar`.

What I want is for my program, App, to run another Java program. And then kill itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program). Check whether that helps you out. Note that it looks like it is platform dependent, so what platform are you using?

Comment: What OS are your using?

Comment: Windows 7, sorry forgot to mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use (on Linux)

```
nohup java -jar someOtherProgram.jar &
```

and in Windows

```
start /min java -jar someOtherProgram.jar
```

or

```
javaw -jar someOtherProgram.jar
```

Comment: Hm, with the Windows line, it says that it cannot find my program: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start /min java -jar someOtherProgram.jar");`

Comment: check my updated answer. You may want to try javaw (javaw.exe)

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold I think you'll find javaw will have the same effect as using java, this is how the OS chains processes together, meaning the current process can't end till any child process terminate...

Comment: @JustKidding You should use ProcessBuilder and set the "directory" property to set the start location of the program

Comment: MadProgrammer, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997718/difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe

"javaw.exe is the command which will not wait for the application to complete." means the shell dont know it's still running even when it think it's already finished.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold Yep, but that's not the same thing as a parent->child process chain, we're not talking about a shell here ;)

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold Owww, you might be right (about JavaW) - wasn't able to get this to work under Java 6 for some reason, nice ;)

Comment: @madprogrammer there's nothing in General which would prevent a parent process from exiting while child processes are still running.  In this case the OP was using the java command which intentionally waited for the child - but it's not the OS forcing that.

Answer (score 3):

Under Windows, I believe you need to use something like...

```
cmd /B start "" java -jar someOtherProgram.jar
```

Remember, if your path contains spaces, it will need to be quoted, for example

```
cmd /B start "" java -jar "path to your/program/someOtherProgram.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that comes to my head is to use the exit() method. It shuts down itself.

```java
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: You should try this, I think you find that until the child process exists, it will hold the JVM open