# Why do I see Eclipse as 'javaw.exe' in Windows task manager?

Tags: java, eclipse, window

Sorry if this is too naive, but shouldn't it be something like eclipse.exe?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997718/difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe

Comment: Is this helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javaw-javaws/8194750#8194750

Comment: Actually it is a good question, I haven't thought about it myself. You have an eclipse.exe binary so why doesn't the process show up as eclipse.exe then? My best guess is that the eclipse.exe is only a smaller bootstrapping executable which forks the actual Java process (by running javaw.exe) and then terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links provided in the comments are quite informative, but if you still aren't able to understand why Eclipse shows as javaw.exe in the Task Manager, then refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javaw-javaws/21542804#21542804). (Excerpt below)

> **javaw**: (java windowed) Application executor not associated with console. So no display of output/errors. Can be used to silently push the output/errors to text files. Mostly used to launch GUI based applications.

Eclipse is a GUI based development tool and hence the process associated with Eclipse reads javaw.exe in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be run as `eclipse.exe`, you can pass in the following parameter in your eclipse configuration file:
`-vm <your java installation folder>\bin\client\jvm.dll`

Comment: Or `<path_to_jdk>\bin` according to the reference http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html and https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a program, which runs upon Java Virtual Machine. javaw.exe is a process, corresponding to JVM.