# Getting the Process id of Tomcat running in Eclipse on Windows

Tags: java, tomcat, process, pid

I need to create a thread dump of the JVM running the Tomcat server from inside Eclipse on a Windows 7 machine.  From the Task Manager I am not able to differentiate between the java.exe and javaw.exe.  I am not sure which one is running Tomcat.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997718/difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer from the one posted in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997726/259889):

> java.exe is the console app while javaw.exe is windows app
>   (console-less). You can't have Console with javaw.exe.