# How to run program in background

Tags: java, powershell, command-line, jenkins, windows-8

I use Windows 8.1, I start program instance by command line. There is this line

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --ajp13Port=-1 --httpPort=8082
```

Program starts and everything is all right. But i want to hide console from task menu. Is it possible to run program by command line in this way?

Comment: You can use [`javaw` instead of `java`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997718/difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe) to start the application without a console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

1) `javaw` - java without console window to start your application

or

2) `start /b *command*` - to start a background task

Answer (score 2):

Why not using javaw instead of java?