# Suppress windows cmd for system command in Perl

Tags: linux, windows, perl

I am using a system command in Perl to execute java. I have formed an array @args that have different options to execute a jar file.  Something like below:

```
$args[0] = $rootpath."/jre/bin/java";
$args[1] = " -jar \"".$rootpath."/temp/abc.jar\"";
$args[2] = " INP=\"".$inputfilename."\"";
$args[3] = " OUT=\"".$outputfilename."\"";
system(@args);
```

This gives a popup window when executed which I want to suppress and want it to run in background. I want this to be suppressed in Linux also. I tried using tild but it didn't helped as below.

```
my $command = @args;
$output = `$command`;
```

Please help in figuring this out.

Comment: `my $foo = @bar` will give you the **number of elements** in `@bar` because that's what an array will be turned into when used in scalar context.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/233348/how-do-i-create-a-windows-batch-file-that-does-not-show-the-command-prompt-when for Windows.

Comment: Thanks simbabque. I forgot to put double quote around @args. The link you have provided suggests using start $cmd I think for perl which I tried but it doesn't help. What could be the problem?

Comment: `java` should use the console in which your script is already executing. I have no idea why it's opening a second console for you.

Comment: I have a C++ application that is calling perl scripts from which I am using system command. So the perl script is not running in any console. It opens new console when I am calling system command to execute java.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using Win32::SetChildShowWindow(0) and it worked perfectly. I have build Win32 module and linked Win32 library to my application. After adding below code before calling the system command no pop-up command prompt window is displayed.

```
Win32::SetChildShowWindow(0) 
if defined &Win32::SetChildShowWindow;
```

You can also follow discussion on this here: [Perlmonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1130953)

Answer (score 1):

Use `javaw` instead of `java`.

This most probably boils down to changing the first line to

```
$args[0] = $rootpath."/jre/bin/javaw";
```

See also [Difference between java.exe and javaw.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997718/difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe)

Comment: Perfect solution what I was looking for to remove console window when calling java as system command in perl. Tons of thanks.